# Unidentifiable process always running

Tags: iphone, malware

According to the screen time monitor on my iPhone there's process called "isha.sadhguru.org" on all day and responsible for an average running time of 20 hours per day:

[image]

It's unclear why this process is running. I have discovered a meditation app from the same fellow but this has never been installed on my device.

How do I get rid of this process?

Comment: What iOS? There was a bug at one point where the screen time would falsely hang onto some links & report the user had basically been staring at them for days. I do doubt sadhguru would be interested in hacking your phone, he seems a gentle soul, & funny at times [& no, I don't subscribe to any form of mysticism or do yoga;)

Comment: iOS 15.3.1 and yes it does look like the world can benefit from some of his advice. 

Comment: Have you [force-restarted your iPhone](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/force-restart-iphone-iph8903c3ee6/ios)? When various iPhones over the ages have gone a little haywire, a FR sometimes resolves the problem. No guarantees, but worth a try.